# Issue scraping dynamic content with mechanize

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize, dynamic-content

I'm attempting to scrape search results on a streaming video website. The search results are loaded dynamically, which I think is why I'm not getting correct results. After I submit the form and get my results.html back, it's always the home page without the search having been done... Any help would be great, if Mechanize simply doesn't have this capability maybe someone could point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance.

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()

br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.set_handle_equiv(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla')]

br.open('http://movietv.to')

br.select_form(nr=0)
br.form.set_all_readonly(False)
br.form.set_value("Godfather", nr=0)

resp = br.submit()

with open('results.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(resp.read())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Mechanize` is not exactly a good candidate for this particular "dynamic" site. The easiest high-level approach would be to go with browser automation via [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/).

Though I made it work using [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) HTML parser. The key things to achieve that were 1) the movies are loaded via an XHR request to `http://movietv.to/index/loadmovies` and 2) this request requires a `token` to be sent - it can be extracted from a `script` element on the main page.

The complete working implementation:

```
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


search = "Godfather"

token_pattern = re.compile(r'var token_key="(.*?)";')
with requests.Session() as session:  # maintaining web-scraping session
    session.headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36"}

    # extract token
    response = session.get("http://movietv.to/")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    script = soup.find("script", text=token_pattern).get_text()
    match = token_pattern.search(script)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError("Cannot find token!")

    token = match.group(1)

    # search for the movies
    response = session.post("http://movietv.to/index/loadmovies", data={
        "loadmovies": "showData",
        "page": "1",
        "abc": "All",
        "genres": "",
        "sortby": "Popularity",
        "quality": "All",
        "type": "movie",
        "q": search,
        "token": token
    })

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    for movie in soup.select("div.item"):
        title = movie.find("h2", class_="movie-title")

        print(title.get_text())
```

Prints the found movies:

```
The Godfather
The Godfather: Part II
The Godfather: Part III
```